# Loop in functions calling each other

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, class

I have a class that represents a person in a family (FamilyMember).

I implemented the function `setParent` that receives a FamilyMember Object and adds it to the list of `parent` of the current Object.
Exactly the same is done in the `setChild` function.

**The problem**: as one function calls the other (If we set the parent of our current Object we should as well set the current Object as the parent's child), they enter in a loop. => I managed to stop it checking if the object was already in the list. But this means I'm alway doing an unnecessary call to the function.

```
    def setParent(self, parent):
        if not isinstance(parent, FamilyMember):
            raise TypeError("Parent must be set to a FamilyMember")
        if parent in self.parents:
            print("parent already in the list")
            return
        self.parents.append(parent) 
        parent.setChild(self)


    def setChild(self, child):

        if not isinstance(child, FamilyMember):
            raise TypeError("child must be set to a FamilyMember")
        if child in self.children:
            print("child already in the list")
            return
        self.children.append(child) 
        child.setParent(self)
```

**Posible solution that I dislike**: I could do 2 more functions that do the same but don't call the other function. But this means repeating code, and having 4 different functions, which is not a good practice. 
ex:

```
    def setParent_no_loop(self, parent):
        if not isinstance(parent, FamilyMember):
            raise TypeError("Parent must be set to a FamilyMember")
        if parent in self.parents:
            print("parent already in the list")
            return
        self.parents.append(parent) 

    def setChild(self, child):
        if not isinstance(child, FamilyMember):
            raise TypeError("child must be set to a FamilyMember")
        if child in self.children:
            print("child already in the list")
            return
        self.children.append(child) 
        self.setParent_no_loop(self)
```

**Posible solution that I dislike**: I rewrite the code from the other function into both functions. Which, again is rewriting code, and its not really elegant:

```
    def setParent_no_loop(self, parent):
        if not isinstance(parent, FamilyMember):
            raise TypeError("Parent must be set to a FamilyMember")
        if parent in self.parents:
            print("parent already in the list")
            return
        self.parents.append(parent)
        parent.children.append(self)
```

**The question** is, can you find an elegant way to solve this problem?

Comment: `I managed to stop it checking if the object was already in the list.` - That is the elegant solution. There is nothing wrong with checking to see if a member is already in a list before adding, and you should be doing this anyways as a safety feature for that function. If you really want to avoid the function call (which isn't a major performance penalty), you could check `if self not in parent.children` then call `parent.setChild(self)` (for the setParent example).

Comment: Since the first way you mentioned does print the `parent/child already in the list` you could simply remove that print statement so it doesn't happy everytime you add a parent/child. If you want to have that sort of error checking just return a boolean value instead. That way you can optionally check if ever needed.

Comment: `elegant ` can be subjective, what would satisfy you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest designing the methods as follows:

```py
def add_child(self, child):
    self.children.append(child)
    child.parents.append(self)

def add_parent(self, parent):
    parent.add_child(self)
```

There is no need for these methods to be recursive or mutually-recursive. Add your own error-handling code as necessary.

Comment: This works, but I would still check for the existence of a parent or child in the list before appending. Such a check is minimal and promotes type safety.

Comment: Yes, of course. I did say you should add your own error-handling code as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could hash the objects and check if they exist in the other via the hash comparison at the start of the set function? I've done it that way below (because that's safest if the user forgets to do the comparison first), but you could also do it before you call the set function to avoid the extra function call.

```py
class FamilyMember(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.relations = set()
        self.hashval = hash(self)
        self.parents = set()
        self.children = set()

    def knowsAbout(self, otherhash):
        if otherhash in self.relations:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def setParent(self, newParent):
        if not self.knowsAbout(newParent):
            self.relations.add(newParent.hashval)
            self.parents.add(newParent)
            newParent.addChild(self)

    def setChild(self, newChild):
        if not self.knowsAbout(newChild):
            self.relations.add(newChild.hashval)
            self.children.add(newChild)
            newChild.addParent(self)
```

It's still an extra function call, but the hash comparison is a quick one at least.

Comment: This won't work correctly unless all of the hash values are distinct, since you are only storing the hashes and checking if the hashes are the same. It is better to implement `__hash__` and `__eq__` methods, and store the objects themselves in the set.

Comment: Alternatively you could store the object ids in the set, instead of their hashes. `id(self)` is guaranteed to be unique and unchanging, so you don't even need to add a field to the object. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id

Answer (score 0):

Make `parents` and `children` sets instead of lists.

Then in each method just add and don't worry about it.

```
def setParent(self, parent):
    if not isinstance(parent, FamilyMember):
        raise TypeError("Parent must be set to a FamilyMember")
    self.parents.add(parent) 
    parent.children.add(self)


def setChild(self, child):
    if not isinstance(child, FamilyMember):
        raise TypeError("child must be set to a FamilyMember")
    self.children.add(child) 
    child.parents.add(self)
```